# How to remove the hovering navigation menu while in Google Data Studio Presentation mode?

Tags: looker-studio

How do I control if the hovering navigation menu appears when the data studio dashboard that I have created enters presentation mode? There are already in-dashboard controls and this menu gets in the way, more than it helps.

Comment: I don't know which navigation menu are you talking about (is the navigation bar when there is more than one page? Is the chart header that appears when the mouse is hover?). Could you be more precise?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz In presentation mode when there is more than one page, there appears a hovering menu at the bottom left of the screen that only goes away when you do not interact with it. It contains a play icon with arrow besides it to change views, a page chooser, a page timer, viewer option etc. It is cumbersome when viewing from a phone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to hide this control box.  However, if they bother you, I think you do not really need presentation mode.

You can mimic the presentation mode, hiding Header, Navigation Bar and setting the window to full screen.

In File > Theme And Layout > Layout > View Mode:

- Select "Initially hidden" for Header visibility;
- Select "Hidden" for Navigation type;
- Select "Fit to width" for Display mode;
- Un-select "Has margin".

Then, just set your browser to fullscreen during visualization (F11 on Windows, or just expand the window in MacOS).  This way you get the same result, without the presentation controls.

Comment: Thanks, but I was needing this solution especially for mobile visualization. (I see now that I didn't mention this anywhere). 
Also, I have coincidentally done just as you have mentioned to make the display nicer.